# fork() - closing server

Tags: c, sockets, unix, ipc, fork

I have wrote a server program that can handle multiple client by using fork().  I have a signal handler, error checking where needed, and everything works correctly.  I have it set up where if a client enter 'quit', the server should stop accepting connections, let the opened clients finish their communication, and close once all clients are closed.  To do this, whenever 'quit' is entered, I have an int flag that is set to 0.  Since the variables in each child process are only for that process, and do not affect the other child processes or the parent process, I can't keep track of when the flag is set to 0.  In my signal handler I am checking

```
    if( count == 0 && flag == 0)
    //close server and exit program
```

count is the number of clients opened which after they are all closed will obviously be zero ( this has been error checked to make sure it is correct).  Does anyone know of a way I can create flag that can be set inside one client, and have that same value for every client?  If that makes sense..  I am coding in C by the way.

Comment: Lots of ways to do this.  A helpful keyphrase to know here would be "inter-process communication" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a single server for everyone to speak to, he will broadcast back to all the clients to update them with the client count, but in essence without a lot of complication to speak and keep track of all the other clients is a bit of a challenge.

This would also be a place to route and traffic messages between different clients.

Hopefully this shines some light.

Answer (score 0):

The child process receiving the `quit` command needs to send a signal (such as `SIGUSR1` -- I don't recommend `SIGTERM` for this purpose unless you are going to be closing out all the clients as soon as possible) to its parent, and let the parent set the flag in *its* memory space in that signal handler.  (The parent can let everyone know its pid by just storing the results of `getpid()` somewhere.)

Comment: this would work and I almost used the SIGUSR1, but then I remembered the exit() status.. duh.. which took me a couple seconds to add in and everything worked like i wanted

Comment: Well, you didn't say that a client issuing `quit` was going to disconnect right away, just that the server should begin an orderly shutdown. :-)

Comment: yes, definitely should have put that somewhere in my details but I did learn more from these answers than I ever would have :) thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

There are many IPC mechanisms that can do this... in particular semaphores come to mind.  You could create a set of two semaphores, and use one for your child count and one for your quit flag.  When you start your program, the client count would be initialized to zero, and the quit flag would be initialized to one.  When each child is started, it should add one to the client count... and subtract one when it exits.  When a client receives the quit command, it would zero the quit flag.  The main program will know when everything is done when both semaphores reach zero.

Or (if possible) you could just start threads instead of forking processes, and use two global `int`s for `count` and `flag` and a global mutex to protect them.  The pthreads API is fairly easy to use for simple things where not a lot of inter-thread communication needs to occur, and creating a thread is faster than `fork`+`exec`.